# puppeteer link content scraping

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I learned puppeteer. I succeeded in crawling posts, nicknames, dates, and links. However, I want to scrap the contents of link pages in the result value. I mean, access the link of the result value and then scrape content nickname, comment etc.

```
await page.waitForTimeout('5000')
console.log('crawlling start')
const cafecrawlling = await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('#iframe')
  const Post_name = Array.from(document.querySelector('#iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-of-type .board-list .inner_list .article')).map((v) => v.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, '')) // post name
  const Post_link = Array.from(document.querySelector('#iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('tr > td:first-of-type .board-list .inner_list .article')).map((v)=> v.href) // link
  const Post_nickname = Array.from(document.querySelector('#iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('tr > td:nth-of-type(2) .p-nick .m-tcol-c')).map((v) => v.textContent) //nick name
  const Post_date = Array.from(document.querySelector('#iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('tr > td:nth-of-type(3)')).map((v)=> v.textContent) // date
  return Post_name.map((v, i) => {
    return {
      postname: v,
      postlink: Post_link[i],
      nickname: Post_nickname[i],
      postdate: Post_date[i],
    }
  })
});
console.log(cafecrawlling)
console.log('crawlling end')
```

result is

```
{postname: 'Do I need this?',
postlink: 'https://cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=10094499&page=1&inCafeSearch=true&searchBy=0&query=%EB%B3%B4%EB%A5%B4%EB%A5%B4&includeAll=&exclude=&include=&exact=&searchdate=all&media=0&sortBy=date&articleid=62268118&referrerAllArticles=true',
nickname: 'cocodel',
postdate: '2022.08.20.'}

{postname: 'bla bla bla',
postlink: 'https://cafe.naver.com/ca-fe/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=10094499&page=1&inCafeSearch=true&searchBy=0&query=%EB%B3%B4%EB%A5%B4%EB%A5%B4&includeAll=&exclude=&include=&exact=&searchdate=all&media=0&sortBy=date&articleid=62270047&referrerAllArticles=true',
nickname: 'ziziu',
postdate: '2022.08.21.'}
```

Comment: Part of the code you already have, which you are not showing, instructs puppeteer to load the URL that you are currently scraping, right? So, use that code, with the URLs from the `postlink` properties, to continue scraping.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes. how to continue scraping URLs from postlink properties?

Comment: As I said, you already have the code to do this; the code you used to connect to the original site and scrape the links you got. Use that code. If you need help, share that code.